Question regarding period of functions resulting from algebraic operations of functions
The method to find the period of functions resulting from algebraic operations of functions in my textbook is as follows
Say f(x) has period $p = m/n$($m, n \in N$ and coprime) and f(x) has period $q = r/s$($q,s \in N$ and coprime) let $t$ be the LCM of $p$ and $q$
$$t = \frac{LCM(m,r)}{HCF(n,s)}$$
Here t is the period of $f + g$
I tried using this method for the following example
$$f(x) = |\sin 4x| + |\cos 4x|$$
The period of $|\sin 4x|$ is $\pi/4$ and so is the period of $|\cos 4x|$ using the formula above the period $f(x)$ is computed to be $\pi/4$.
However the period of the function is $\pi/8$ and the book says that $t$ is not the period if $k$ exits less than $t$ which is also the period.
Well is their any way to find the smallest possible period?
As intelligent guessing will not work for complex questions, any help would be appreciated!
